# error when I use typeconverter for room. near "?": syntax error in "UPDATE aspirationDetail SET childId = ?,? WHERE id = ?"

Tags: kotlin, android-room

```
@Entity(tableName = "aspirationDetail")
@TypeConverters(MutableListTypeConverter::class)
data class AspirationDetail(
    @PrimaryKey val id: String ,
    var description: String,
    var childId:MutableList<String?> ,
    var parentId: String?,
)

class MutableListTypeConverter{
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromString(value: String?): MutableList<String?>{
        return value?.split(",")?.toMutableList() ?: mutableListOf()
    }
    @TypeConverter
    fun toString(value: MutableList<String?>): String?{
        return if (value == null){
            null
        }else{
            value.joinToString { "," }
        }
    }
}


@Dao
interface AspirDetailDAO{
     
    @Query("UPDATE aspirationDetail SET childId = :childId WHERE id = :id")
    suspend fun updateChildId(id: String,childId: MutableList<String?>)

}
```

these above are my Entity, Typeconverter and DAO. And when I call DAO, it comes out an error message that says following:

> near "?": syntax error in "UPDATE aspirationDetail SET childId = ?,? WHERE id = ?"

I am new to android development knowing a little about programming.

Comment: thank you for your editing that helped make my question more straightforward.@James Z.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about type converting. Type converters work when you are trying to read/write from/to `Room` via defined `Entities`.

Your update query can work but you would have to operate with types Room knows implicitly(no lists) since you are not using entities.

```
@Query("UPDATE aspirationDetail SET childId = :childId WHERE id = :id")
suspend fun updateChildId(id: String, childId: String?)
```

You have to serialize it manually before the call.

```
val aspirationDetailId: String = "foo"
val childIds: MutableList<String> = MutableListOf("1","2","3")

aspirDetailDAO.updateChildId(aspirationDetailId, childIds.joinToString { "," })
```

Or alternatively, you update the instance of `AspirationDetail` to have the values that you want and use `@Update` directly

```
@Update
suspend fun updateChildId(aspirationDetail: AspirationDetail)
```

```
val aspirationDetail: AspirationDetail(
    id = "foo",
    description = "bar",
    childId = mutableListOf("1", "2", "3"),
    parentId = "?"
)
aspirDetailDAO.update(aspirationDetail)
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your passionate and professional answer. But l have something not understood yet. I am using Hilt to provide instances of the database. So does that mean it doesn't "read/write from/to Room via defined Entities" ?

Comment: Read/Write in this context are operations from DAOs(Data Access Objects). The point was that you either operate with basic types that can be used in SQL query or use @Entitiy as a whole. The only thing Hilt does here is that he provides you with an instance of Room database class that has mentioned DAOs that are used to make changes with the data.

Comment: I probably understand it. 
So the annotation   
[at]TypeConverters(MutableListTypeConverter::class)
data class AspirationDetail(
...     
 could work  well with @Entity as a whole(that is, when I use
   [at]Upsert
    suspend fun upsert(aspir: AspirationDetail)
or 
   [at]Upsert
    suspend fun upsertAll(aspirs: List<AspirationDetail>)"）
but can not work well with 
   [at]Query("UPDATE aspirationDetail SET childId = :childId WHERE id = :id")
    suspend fun updateChildId(id: String,childId: MutableList<String?>)  .
Do I misunderstand it?

Comment: @Tom2100 Yeah, that's basically it. I think You can maybe even make the converter class an `object` so you can call it statically from anywhere for the sake of consistency but I have not tried it myself yet and I don't know if it can be `object`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try and tell you later about whether the converter class can be an object without removing the annotation @TypeConverters... . Right now I am working with a UI layer problem which is a barrier to displaying results for updateChildId.

Comment: You are right! It can be an object and we can pass it as a parameter of the annotation @TypeConverters(...). Thank you so much!